# How to install hashcat-utlis into the system 18.04?

Tags: 18.04

I compiled the binaries as i have been told by README.md, but I need other apps like airgeddon to detect it.

Comment: Hello  Game dasher, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most unix applications will look for other applications in your PATH environment variable. Once it's copied to one of the PATH directories most applications should find it.

View your PATH env variable with the following command:

`echo $PATH`

More about the PATH env variable: https://kb.iu.edu/d/acar

Some applications may also allow you to specify the path for applications they use. Check their configuration files or command line options.